# How to add image Bitmap in the Gallery component?

Tags: android

Is there any way to insert a bitmap image in the gallery component?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just create and return an ImageView with your bitmap in your gallery adapter

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      final List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Gallery galleryV = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        galleryV.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
          @Override
          public int getCount() {
            return bitmaps.size();
          }
          @Override
          public Object getItem(int position) {
            return bitmaps.get(position);
          }
          @Override
          public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
          }
          @Override
          public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
              convertView = new ImageView(MyActivity.this);
            }
            ((ImageView) convertView).setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));
            return convertView;
          }
        });
      }
    }
```